# How to Load a Different Ribbon in Access at Runtime

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to change the main ribbon (which is loaded when Access is opened) for another ribbon saved in the **USysRibbons** table, on the **OnLoad** event of a form. My need it to have a ribbon for each form.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Forms and reports have a RibbonName property. Try that. I have only used it for reports but should work for forms as well.

Comment: @June7 I can't believe man. So simple! Thanks a lot June.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest method is to use form RibbonName property. Ribbons defined in USysRibbon table will be available in this property dropdown list.

Comment: is there a way to rename the **File** tab? I know that it is not possible to hide it but, I'd like to rename it at lest.
I also want to align a control inside the ribbon to the right by using **LayoutContainer**, unsuccessfully. why doesn't it work in Access?

Comment: Those are new questions. Should create questions. I have no idea if File tab can be renamed - I doubt it. I have never tried to align control in ribbon - not even sure what you mean by LayoutContainer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks June.

Comment: If answer resolves question, please mark accepted. Upvote always nice as well.